# Breadth First Search Python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

OK well. The incipit is that the code works, however, not all the time and more than anything else I would like to know if this type of solution for this type of research is optimal or not

The first part of the code, not made by me, completes very well the production of random mazes with insertion, that is my work, of an end and a beginning (2 = beginning 3 = end) in the second part I use a multilevel dictionary to create the tree from the matrix that is given to me by the function that creates the maze.
This tree, as I thought, blocks its growth when we find the end, in this way, for this specific type of research we just have to scroll along the tree to see how long we have reached the end and what path we have used. Did I do everything right? do you find solutions to improve the code?

```
class Tree_Build():
    def find_start(Z):
        for x in range(1,len(Z[0])):
            for y in range(1,len(Z)):
                if Z[x,y]==2:
                    return (x,y)

    def node(x,y,fx,fy,tree,deep,num,stat):
        tree[num][1]=x
        tree[num][2]=y
        tree[num][3]=fx
        tree[num][4]=fy
        tree[num][5]=deep
        tree[num][6]=0
        tree[num][7]=stat
        return tree

    def search(tree,deep,check):
        for i in range(1,len(tree)-1):
            if tree[i][5]==deep:
                if tree[i][6]==0:
                    if check==1:
                        tree[i][6]=1
                    return tree[i][1],tree[i][2],tree[i][5]
        return False

    def check(x,y,tree):
        for i in range(0,len(tree)):
            if tree[i][1]==x:
                if tree[i][2]==y:
                    return True
        return False

    def create_tree(Z):
        tree = defaultdict(dict)
        deep=0
        stat=0
        num=1
        x,y=Tree_Build.find_start(Z)
        tree[0][1]=x
        tree[0][2]=y
        tree[0][5]=0
        tree[0][7]=2
        while True:
            move=False
            if Z[x+1,y]!=1:
                if Tree_Build.check(x+1,y,tree)==False:
                    tree=Tree_Build.node(x+1,y,x,y,tree,deep+1,num,stat)
                    num+=1
                    move=True
                    if Z[x+1,y]==3:
                        stat=3
                        num-=1
                        tree=Tree_Build.node(x+1,y,x,y,tree,deep+1,num,stat)
                        break

            if Z[x,y+1]!=1:
                if Tree_Build.check(x,y+1,tree)==False:
                    tree=Tree_Build.node(x,y+1,x,y,tree,deep+1,num,stat)
                    num+=1
                    move=True
                    if Z[x,y+1]==3:
                        stat=3
                        num-=1
                        tree=Tree_Build.node(x+1,y,x,y,tree,deep+1,num,stat)
                        break

            if Z[x-1,y]!=1:
                if Tree_Build.check(x-1,y,tree)==False:
                    tree=Tree_Build.node(x-1,y,x,y,tree,deep+1,num,stat)
                    num+=1
                    move=True
                    if Z[x-1,y]==3:
                        stat=3
                        num-=1
                        tree=Tree_Build.node(x+1,y,x,y,tree,deep+1,num,stat)
                        break

            if Z[x,y-1]!=1:
                if Tree_Build.check(x,y-1,tree)==False:
                    tree=Tree_Build.node(x,y-1,x,y,tree,deep+1,num,stat)
                    num+=1
                    move=True
                    if Z[x,y-1]==3:
                        stat=3
                        num-=1
                        tree=Tree_Build.node(x+1,y,x,y,tree,deep+1,num,stat)
                        break



            #if move==True:
            if Tree_Build.search(tree,deep,0)==False:
                deep+=1
            else:
                x,y,deep=Tree_Build.search(tree,deep,1)

            print(tree)


        return(tree)
```

Well. in one of the few cases where this code does not work as expected I paused the execution and I have this message (Backend TkAgg is interactive backend.) Turning interactive mode on.) and fails to go beyond the third node.
In another case I receive the message:

Exception ignored in: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C: \ Users \ MkPc \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python37-32 \ lib \ tkinter \ __ init__.py", line 3504, in **del**
    self.tk.call ('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in the main loop

Any suggestions?

Comment: If there are no actual bugs/problems with your code, and you're looking for only suggestions/improvements, https://codereview.stackexchange.com might be the place to go with this question instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: *"the code works, however, not all the time"*: we would then say that the code does not work correctly. If your question is about code review, see above comment. If you want to focus on why it does not work correctly *all the time*, then rewrite your question providing a case where the output is not what you want, providing the expected output.

Comment: Thank you both! as soon as I fix this problem on the code I see if they have suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: You just have the line `tree=Tree_Build.node(x+1,y,x,y,tree,deep+1,num,stat)` four times. I think the other ones should be for x-1, y+1 nad y-1 respectively.